# How to send back non-stringified data in serverles aws

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless

I am using serverless and am trying to send back something else other than a stringified object, but it just keeps giving me back, `Internal Server Error`.

Here is what I tried

```
module.exports.testPost = (event, context, callback) => {
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.parse(event.body) // event.body was tried as well
  };

  callback(null, response);
};
```

I am assuming that you are to send it back as `JSON.stringify()` to work. What I am asking is how can I send a raw object back instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik by default it sends a raw object back but its body is the one that is stringified.

```
module.exports.test = (event, context, callback) => {
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message: 'Ola'
    }),
  };

  callback(null, response);
  // callback(null, JSON.stringify(response));
  // This is an error because you replied with a string
};
```

So I would assume you're asking to NOT stringified the body? Well I don't think it is possible as of the moment, I would assume that Amazon wants the body format to be in **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** format thats why it is stringified.